# how to copy latest directory from list of directories on date format

Tags: linux, shell, cp

How to copy latest directory from list of directories on date format?

I am using below command but it is copying all directories

```
ls -t | head -1 | cp -r * /destination
```

Directory is like below.

03-07-2019-06-30

Comment: What do you think `cp -r * /destination` does? Perhaps `cp -r $(ls -td */ | head -n 1) /destination`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp -R "`ls -dtr1 /source_dir_path/* | tail -1`" /destination_pth/
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1` will print the latest directory created in the current folder. By using `$()` you can take the output as input of `cp` command.
Hope it helps your query.

```
  cp $(ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1) /your_directory/
```